# DOM change - no effect. Effect visible only if changed with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, woocommerce

Weird problem. I'm modifying shop template:
https://demo.themeisle.com/shop-isle/product-category/clothing/dresses/

At this moment when you hover product's picture there will show "add to cart" button. This is .
Under picture there is price

I prepared code:

```
var from = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-Price-amount amount");
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.each(from, function(i, el) {
        jQuery(el.parentNode.parentNode).find(jQuery(".product-button-wrap")).append(el);
    });
});
```

Nothing happens. This code work only if I set timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {

var from = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-Price-amount amount");
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.each(from, function(i, el) {
        jQuery(el.parentNode.parentNode).find(jQuery(".product-button-wrap")).append(el);
    });
});

}, 10000);
```

Of course timeout it's not a solution. I was trying to find out minimal time to obtain best behavior but it's impossible. I have feeling that every browser (and version...) needs personalized time setting.

I thought that after 24-hour break I will get some brillant idea, but that doesn't work, no more ideas.

--- EDIT ---
OK, thanks for pointed mixed common js with jquery - I will correct that later.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var from = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-Price-amount amount");  
    jQuery.each(from, function(i, el) {
        jQuery(el.parentNode.parentNode).find(jQuery(".product-button-wrap")).append(el);
        console.log(el);
    });
});
```

That's logical that `var from` should be inside `ready` but this still doesn't work. No effect.
If I use in loop console.log it will return for me html code of `el`.

--- EDIT ---

Thanks. While testing I noticed something. I wanted append element `.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount` to element `.product-button-wrap`. But how can I do that if element `.product-button-wrap` isn't originally in source? This object is created dynamically (I don't know how).

-- EDIT --

OK. I checked JS files and found code adding to DOM .product-button-wrap so I putted my code there and now everything works. Thanks for help.

Comment: Move your `var from` line _inside_ the `ready` function. You can't pick up an element if the DOM isn't ready which is what `ready` checks for.

Comment: Why you mix common js and jquery ?

Comment: ^ yup. `$('.woocommerce-Price-amount amount')` makes more sense.

Comment: Note that `getElementsByClassName()` looks for elements with all provided classes, so the jQuery equivalent would be `$('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount')`

Comment: I made edits in question because I noticed that element to which I wanted to append doesn't exist originally in source. How can I append element to element which is created after my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're running your code *before* the DOM has loaded. You need to retrieve the elements within the `document.ready` event handler.

Also note that you have an odd mix of native JS and jQuery methods. I'd suggest using one or the other, like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.product-button-wrap').append(this);
  });
});
```

Also note that `.parent().parent()` should be replace by a single call to `closest()`, but I can't give you an exact example of that without seeing your HTML.

Comment: Thanks. While testing your code I noticed something. I wanted append element `.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount` to element `.product-button-wrap`. But how can I do that if element `.product-button-wrap` isn't originally in source? This object is created dynamically (I don't know how).